# Do I need to change my host OS to something like Tails if I already have Tails running in a VM if I want to be protected on the interenet?

Tags: windows, operating-systems, virtualization

First let me say sorry if I sound like a script kitty, because I am. Now on to my question.

So I want to be protected on the internet when I go on the deep web, do banking etc. I use Tails to protect myself since it is a very secure OS.

I use SSL over OpenVpn to connect, and I run that on my VM and that seems to do the job. Currently my host OS is Windows 7 Pro Service Pack 1. Is it a vulnerability to use Windows as my host OS vs Tails (yes I do know that I could get a virus on windows and they could spy on my VM.)

I guess another way to phrase it is could someone hack me, who only sees my VM, and still get to my windows machine?

Also would it be better to use another flavor of Linux, such as Kali? I have it as a vm and it works well, but as stated previously I am a script kitty atm so I am not good at penetration testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to create a bootable USB/CD for Tails and not run it through a VM. Tails forces your internet connection through Tor, so if there any vulnerabilities with Tor (exit nodes, etc...) then you will be compromised.

For internet banking and things that require more security, it might be best to install Linux (Debian is a good distro) alongside Windows, create an encrypted Debian volume and use this for tasks that require higher security than your Windows system can offer.

Note: As per Tails Documentation on Virtualization. It is not recommended to run Tails in a VM. Reference: https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/virtualization/index.en.html#index1h1

Comment: I agree, running tails in a VM is redundant since you can just boot from it when you need it, except of course if you need both OSs concurrently in which case a VM is justified and probably fine regardless of the OS hosting the VM..

Comment: Can you explain what the risk is for running Tails in a VM? You sort of say don't do it, but don't explain why.

Comment: Good point @NeilSmithline Post updated